# Draw horizontal bars in a bar graph with circularly repeating widths

Tags: matlab, for-loop

[image]

To try to draw this figure, the code I used is:

```
figure; 
axis equal;
axis([0 100 0 100]); 

 for i = 0:10:90
 rectangle('position',[0 i (i+10) 10], 'facecolor', 0.5+zeros(1,3));
 end
```

With this code the steps keep increasing in size and do not return to 10 when i = 50. How do I keep the steps in the range from 10 to 50 with this single `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't so bad!  Just add in a `mod` statement in your `rectangle` call:

```
figure; 
axis equal;
axis([0 100 0 100]); 

for i = 0:10:90
    rectangle('position',[0 i mod(i,50)+10 10], 'facecolor', 0.5+zeros(1,3));
end
```

We note that your loop goes from 0 to 90 in steps of 10.  What the `mod` statement is doing is that it allows a wrap around once you exceed 50.  Therefore, at `i = 0`, doing `mod(0,50)` gives us 0 and we need to add 10 so that your initial width is 10.  Next at `i = 10`, doing `mod(10,50) + 10` gives us 20, and we keep going until `i = 40`, where we have a width of 50.  Next at `i = 50`, we should reset the width to 10 and `mod(50,50) = 0` as there is no remainder.  From the look of your graph, once the width reaches 50, you would like this to be reset to a width of 10, and so that's what the `mod` operator is for.

This is what I get:

[image]